# Vue keydown event not firing on div

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As the title says, I can't get my event to fire.

```
@keydown="keyPressed($event)"
```

This is how it looks currently,but I've tried it with tabIndex and appending in on mount like this :

```
mounted(){
        let container=document.querySelector('#course')
        container.addEventListener('keydown',(e)=>{
            console.log(e)
        })

    }
```

**Template**

```html
<div id="course" tabindex="0" @keydown="keyPressed($event)"> 
  <div class="snake"></div>
</div>
```

Hence,nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show the part where you added its `tabindex`?

Comment: @cSharp ` <div id="course" tabindex="0" @keydown="keyPressed($event)">
        <div class="snake"></div>
    </div>`

Answer (score 2):

I think in vue, a better practice would be to select the element using `ref` instead of a `querySelector` especially if it can be referenced in the same component.

Also using `@keydown` just attaches a `keydown` event listener to the element, so there is no need to do `addEventListener`.

[Working example in vue](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<script setup>
  import { onMounted } from 'vue';
  
  const courseDiv = $ref(null);
  
  const keyPressed = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  }

</script>

<template>
  <div ref="courseDiv" id="course" tabindex="0" @keydown="keyPressed($event)"> 
    <div class="snake">snek</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: where is onMounted being used here